# How can i run two independent docker containers with nginx?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have one VPS, but two developers with projects. And we need to deploy 2 different websites there. And both websites have their own Nginx container for its project. How can we manage 2 different nginx containers on the VPS without conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

The canonical nginx solution is that each website will have only it's own nginx configuration file which is very specific and will serve only clients coming from the correct host.

That way there is one nginx server serving both websites.

It can be done by adding the conf files inside the nginx container:
`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/website1.conf` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/website1.conf`

The files content will look like:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name website1.hostname;

    location / {
        .....    
    }
}
```